# Передача данных express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Есть такой участок кода на сервере. Выполняется скрипт к бд и получаются данные в ответ. Когда идёт ответ сервера, то данные разбиваются по пакетам и посылаются на фронт. Однако, проблема в том, что если на сервере не группировать их в один большой объём, то на фронте будет всегда приходить только первый пакет.
Проще говоря, нужно чтобы на фронте, когда идёт запрос к базе данных, данные подгружались постепенно, а не одним большим скопом. Возможно ли это?
Если да, то как на фронте реализовать получение данных?

```
//...
const script = spawn('./script.sh')
script.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        if (scriptData == undefined) {
            scriptData = data;
        }
        else scriptData += data;
    })
//...
script.on('exit', function (code) {
    if (!code) {
        res.status(200);
        res.end(scriptData);
    }
})
//...
```

Со стороны фронта выглядит так:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
```

url - адрес, куда стучаться и откуда приходит ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ был найден. 
На фронте было всё в порядке, т.е. запрос отправлялся и ждал ответа от сервера.
Сама выдача ответа сервером была неправильной. Node.js я никогда не изучал, отсюда и вытекло. 
На беке, как видно из строки, `scriptData += data`, данные скапливаются и затем отправляются в строке `res.end(scriptData)`. Здесь стоит пояснить цитированием из [документации](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding_callback), что делает метод `end`:

> Этот метод сообщает серверу, что все заголовки и тело ответа были
>   отправлены; этот сервер должен считать это сообщение завершенным.

Если необходимо, чтобы данные не одной частью отправлялись, то требуется использовать другой метод, который бы не завершал ответ от сервера, а передавал данные по мере их поступления и возможности переслать. Такой был: `response.write`:

> При первом `response.write()` вызове он отправляет буферизованную
>   информацию заголовка и первый фрагмент тела клиенту. При втором
>   `response.write()` вызове Node.js предполагает, что данные будут
>   передаваться в потоковом режиме, и отправляет новые данные отдельно.
>   То есть ответ буферизуется до первого фрагмента тела.

Это и есть решение.

```
script.stdout.on('data', data => {
    res.write(data);
})
script.on('exit', code => {
    if (!code) {
    res.status(200);
    res.end();
}
```

На данный момент всё работает и заметно, как данные постепенно загружаются. Ручаться на сколько это правильно реализовано не буду. Если можно как-то улучшить, то буду рад увидеть.

Answer (score 1):

Классический вариант решения подобных проблем - отправлять на сервер некий параметр, который информирует бэкэнд о том, какие данные брать из БД.

Например, на фронте:

```
var url = 'http://site.ru/getdata?skip=200&fetch=100';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
```

На бэке читаете эти параметры из запроса и передаёте в скрипт.
Примерно, как-то так.

Более конкретно подсказать не могу, т.к. мало подробностей от Вас.

Comment: Если я Вам покажу часть фронта, Вы сможете чуть больше подсказать?

Comment: Я обновил, посмотрите.

Comment: @KeyJibo, я немного дополнил ответ на основании Вашей информации по фронту. Надеюсь, принцип решения Вам понятен.

Comment: Спасибо, мне это будет полезно в будущем знать.